# Read multiple csvs in loop and write as columns in a master csv

Tags: r, loops, csv

Let's say I have two `.csv` tables (I actually have hundreds):

```
Table 1
x     mean_snowcover    useless_data 
1     80                6546156
2     50                6285465
3     60                2859525

Table 2
x    mean_snowcover    useless_data
1    91                87178
2    89                987189
3    88                879278927
```

I want a new table that looks like this:

```
Mean Snowcover
x    Table_1    Table_2
1    80         91
2    50         89
3    60         88
```

This is my current code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/evan/Desktop/Finished Data SGMA/test")

master1=read.csv("New folder/AllSGMA.csv")

temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv$",recursive=FALSE)

###READ CSVS IN LOOP###
for(x in 1:length(temp)){
    mycsv = read.csv(temp[x])
    mean_snowcover=mycsv$mean_snowcover
    master2=cbind(master1,mean_snowcover)
}

write.csv(master2,"Mean Snowcover.csv")
```

But the output is a blank table. I've looked at similar questions on stack overflow but I am unable to figure out what I need to change. I'm fairly new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` and `dplyr::left_join`:

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "x     mean_snowcover    useless_data
1     80                6546156
2     50                6285465
3     60                2859525", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "x    mean_snowcover    useless_data
1    91                87178
2    89                987189
3    88                879278927", header = T)

library(dplyr);
library(magrittr);
Reduce(function(x,y)
    left_join(x, y, by = "x") %>% select(x, contains("snowcover")), list(df1, df2))
#    x mean_snowcover.x mean_snowcover.y
#  1 1               80               91
#  2 2               50               89
#  3 3               60               88
```

This will work on any number of `data.frame`s, as long as they share a common `x` column, and you put them all in a `list`, i.e.

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, ....)
Reduce(function(x,y)
    left_join(x, y, by = "x") %>% select(x, contains("snowcover")), lst)
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that will work for hundreds of csvs, so I don't have to manually read in each one. Any ideas there?

Comment: @J.W.Powell See my answer. Put them all in a `list`, that's all.

Comment: The `data.frame`s should already be in a `list`, if you read them with something similar to `lst <- lapply(csv_file_names, read.csv)`.

Comment: I should've read your question more carefully; better to avoid a `for` loop and use `lapply(temp, read.csv)` to read the files.